# Put Array json on mysql return Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, angularjs, slim

Field 'cats' is a selectbox from Angular app, contain data from table cats, with id, name and module_id.

function on Slim framework for add items..

```
function addItem($section) {

  $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
  $item = json_decode($request->getBody());

  $sql = "INSERT INTO " .$section. " (title, subtitle, slug, excerpt, originalDate, content, cats, published) VALUES (:title, :subtitle, :slug, :excerpt, :originalDate, :content, :cats, :published)";

  try {
      $db = getConnection();
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

      $stmt->bindParam("title", $item->title);
      $stmt->bindParam("subtitle", $item->subtitle);
      $stmt->bindParam("slug", $item->slug);
      $stmt->bindParam("excerpt", $item->excerpt);
      $stmt->bindParam("originalDate", $item->originalDate);
      $stmt->bindParam("content", $item->content);
      $stmt->bindParam("cats", $item->cats);
      $stmt->bindParam("published", $item->published);

      $stmt->execute();
      $item->id = $db->lastInsertId();
      $db = null;

      print_r(json_encode($item));
  } 
  catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
  }
}
```

Angular code, for select box

```
<div class="col-sm-12 m-b-30">
  <p class="f-500 c-black m-b-15">Categorias</p>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick">
    <button type="button" class="btn selectpicker btn-default" ng-model="item.cats" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Selecione a Categoria" aria-expanded="false" data-html="1" data-multiple="1" bs-options="cats.id as cats.name for cats in categorias" bs-select>
      Selecione a categoria <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

cats, return Array on mysql column

Any ideas?!

Example online: http://45.55.73.98/angular-admin/api/v1/s/posts

**Updated!**

```
$cats = null;
foreach ($item->cats as $cat) {
    $cats .= $cat . ",";
}
```

and

```
$stmt->bindParam("cats", $cats);
```

Comment: POST by JSON =  cats
 ["1", "2"]
 
content
 "dfgdfgdfg"
 
excerpt
 "dfgdfgdfg"
 
originalDate
 "2015-06-24T03:00:00.000Z"
 
published
 true
 
section
 "posts"
 
slug
 "gdfg"
 
subtitle
 "gdf"
 
title

Comment: Can you post your Angular code

Comment: I added the code now , the json response this last link

Comment: @MarcoRiesco Can you add your angular controller code too?

Comment: Thanks to all who responded , I got the answer this morning . I will post the result here.

Comment: `$cats=implode(',',$item->cats);` is easier than a loop.

Comment: @MarcoRiesco If you got the answer as you mentioned above, please post it here and accept your own answer. Don't keep the question open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments and the solution is provided in the edit of the question, I am just putting the answer here (modified as suggested in the comment).

the `this->cats` is an array - first convert him to string with:

```
$cats=implode(',',$item->cats);
```

and then bind him:

```
$stmt->bindParam("cats", $cats);
```